# equality check in template parameter

Tags: angular

I cannot figure out what is the proper way to pass the equality check expression as a parameter in angular template. I've checked probably all the possible variations of " and {} but everything gives me runtime error (Invalid key or unexpected token).

```
<progress-button
 striped="{{ main.getState().type == 'check' }}" >
</progress-button>
```

For version above it is:

> [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the
>   expression [{{ main.state.getFlashState().type == 'check' }}] starting
>   at [{ main.state.getFlashState().type == 'check' }}].

What is the way to make it properly?

Comment: progress-button is any custom defined component or any npm component

Comment: @Dimple custom defined React component wrapped with react2angular module

Comment: You could try: `[striped]="main.getState().type == 'check'"`.